# How do I 'refresh' VIM to included newly added files

Tags: vim

I use the [Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025) and [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) plugins and am wondering how to refresh the listings of these two plugins such that a file which has (just) been added to the directory also shows up in these file-browsing plugins.

**Update**

I got the following from the Command-T documentation

```
*:CommandTFlush*
```

|Instructs the plug-in to flush its path cache, causing
                the directory to be rescanned for new or deleted paths
                the next time the file window is shown. In addition, all
                configuration settings are re-evaluated, causing any
                changes made to settings via the |:let| command to be picked
                up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For NERDTree, use <kbd>R</kbd> to refresh your current root or r to update a subdirectory. Take a look at the help from NERDTree (<kbd>?</kbd> in the NERDTree window), it has got some more useful shortcuts.